# ERC Tokens - what can I do with it?

Tags: erc-20

I don't quite understand the hype behind erc tokens.

As I understand it, it is basically an [interface](https://morioh.com/p/ae4e4123233c) for a solidity contract.

So what exactly is the big deal about? The only positive I see is that it allows you to make a well-structured contracts.

Comment: This question is too general, and it is basically subjected to opinion, so I wouldn't be too surprised if it gets closed later on. But one thing that comes to mind is - stocks, shares, options, derivatives, and in general - financial utilities. For example, a token can be used for denoting a share of the company which mints and distributes it. Subsequently, with many different companies using many different tokens to represent their equity, the blockchain itself could then be used for emulating the stock exchange market.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for the comment, One quick  question: I see an example of a token [here](https://studio.ethereum.org/5f9d753626b473001236f315?openFile=README.md). In the mint method, does the `amount` field denote actual money, gwei/eth?

Comment: I see a README file. Where exactly should I be looking?

Comment: actually no worries - I think I got it :) Thanks again for your prompt response and help!

Comment: NP :) ..........